# Parse single value JSON Object

Tags: android, json

I have a server response from server like this -

```
[
    {
        "status": "ok"
    }
]
```

In my app I am using volley to load data:

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest({api_url}, script
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    // Retrieve "status" = "ok"
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                }
            });
```

I want to get "ok" as string so i can compare with something.
How can i get that ?

Comment: Please have a look into above question or just search on Google. It is very basic.

Comment: @VicJordan i searched. Just show me how can i get value of status in java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive a JSONArray at the begining, not a JSONObject. You should replace it

```
    JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest({api_url},
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                    JSONObject statusJson = jsonArray.optJSONObject(0);
                    String status = statusJson.optString("status");
                    Log.d("Status", "Status value == [ " + status + " ]");
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: I just edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution:

```
JSON.parse(response[0]).status
```

JSON.parse is a Javascript function that parse a string object to a valid JSON like object :)